# Why is NightmareJS seemingly hanging in an Express route?

Tags: node.js, express, nightmare

In playing around with Nightmare today, I ran into an issue where I can have a route use `goto` to render a page, save it as a PDF and close with `.end()`. I then use `res.download` to send it. This works on the first run, but on subsequent requests, the server never returns anything and eventually the request times out.

If I save the `index.js` file and let my watcher restart the app, the route will answer a request, but then hangs again.

Hopefully I am missing something simple here. Here is the code for the route:

```
import Nightmare from 'nightmare';

const nightmare = new Nightmare({ show: true });

export default async (req, res) => {
    await nightmare
        .goto('http://duckduckgo.com')
        .wait(1000)
        .insert('#search_form_input_homepage', 'nightmare hangs')
        .click('[type=submit]')
        .wait(2000)
        .pdf('./tmp/results.pdf')
        .end()
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Search failed:', error); // eslint-disable-line
        });

    res.download('./tmp/results.pdf');
};
```

Nightmare 2.10.0, El Capitan, Node 6.9.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42429243/444871 My initial implementation didn't account for closure and that instance was being ended and then reused.

Comment: Any ideas on a good pattern for this? Seems like this is going to create a lot of instances.

Comment: If you're worried about creating too many instances running concurrently, you could use some sort of generic pool (like [this](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool)) to limit the number of instances that can exist at any one time.